# How can I run npm on my Rails app on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, npm-install

I just introduced npm modules into my Rails app (locally) and have been trying to deploy it to Heroku. I recall reading that if I have a package.json file at the root directory of my app, Heroku would detect it and run npm install upon build. My assets, however, are apparently not being installed (for example, webpack). How can I make this work?

Comment: You should be able to `heroku run npm`

Comment: I've done that and the response was `Running npm install on ⬢ soultrust-films... up, run.5830 (Free)
bash: npm: command not found`

Comment: This looks like it can be helpful https://coderwall.com/p/6bmygq/heroku-rails-bower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use multiple buildpacks.

[Using Multiple Buildpacks for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app)

For example, to set a buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
```

And to add a buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

Comment: thank you soo much!!!